# Receiving messages from gRPC on Android App

Tags: android, grpc

I need to create bidirectional communication between an Android App and a server. 
I have seen examples for sending a message to the server but not the other way.
Any idea of how can this be done? A service? Asynctask?

Answer (score 0):

For this case, you will need to make a bidirectional RPC in your proto file:

```
service MyService {
  rpc MyStreamingCall(stream MyRequest)
      returns (stream MyResponse);
}
```

Bidirectional calls work by invoking `myStreamingCall()` on the generated stub, providing a response observer and getting back a request observer.  The request observer can be invoked from your android client to send messages to the server.  When the server responds, your response observer will be invoked with the messages.

As long as your stub has a Channel that was built with ManagedChannelBuilder.executor() set to your own thread pool, the responses will be invoked on one of its threads.  You can do so like:

```
ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress("localhost", 443)
    .executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool())
    .build();
```